# Will a Min-Heap form an array that is already sorted in ascending order?

Tags: algorithm

a) Will a Min-Heap form an array that is already sorted in ascending order?
b) Will a Max-Heap form an array that is already sorted in descending order?

Comment: "no" to both questions

Comment: This is implementation dependent. It is not possible to answer the question (even if we know that no is the answer) without knowing how the heap was implemented in a contiguous zone of memory. But you could answer no anyway just by realizing that there exists 2 distinct valid heaps that contain `{1, 2, 3}`, but only one sorted array contains `{1,2,3}`. Therefore the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

No, value of each node will be less than or equal to its children. When it's stored as array, it may not be in ascending  or descending order as the condition to be min heap is relative to parent child relationship (local) and will not guarantee increasing or decreasing order.
By definition:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-representation-of-binary-heap/
same goes for max heap